# How to check excel cell text contain excel formula or not

Tags: java, excel

I am validating individual cell content of excel. For reading an excel
I am using apache POI. I want to put validation on formulas text , is
there any way that I can check if particular text/String contain excel
formula or not using java?

please suggest some regex or pattern

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the POI dependencies, you can simply check the type of your cell using:

```
if(yourCell!=null && yourCell.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA){
    //....
     }
```

Comment: is there any way on text level, because existing framework parse excel to java object which i cant change, because its used in multiple applications.

Comment: @AjitKamble I don't guess so, as long as I don't know how your said framework deals with excel.

Comment: framework mean on of the existing jar which read excel data and map to VO object , which i used in my application to  insert record into database.

Comment: @AjitKamble if you could just post a snippet of what you've tried before, that would be helpful.

Comment: If you just have the plaintext of the cell contents already in a Java object as a String, for e.g., `String cellContent;` you can test if it is a value or an excel formula by doing `cellContent.startsWith("=");` since all excel formulas begin with an `=` sign..

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD with ".startWith("=") " its not possible in my case because Row.getCell(X) return value without "=" sign . so i modified existing read logic to achieve this.  thanks every one